# Using if statements with ndarray

Tags: if-statement, numpy, where-clause

I am trying to find values below 200 in a 569x462 ndarray I read in from a text file. I want to use numpy.where to find the values... I've tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np

#Load in text file from Sebago
sebago=np.loadtxt('sebagoWatershedElv.txt',skiprows=6)

#Find where elevation is less than 200
lowElv=np.where(sebago[:]<200)
```

But the output shows values less than 200, and some values that are greater than 200...

Comment: Do you want the indices where the values are less than 200, or the values less than 200?

Comment: I would actually like both.

Comment: Shows indices... got it.

Answer (score 2):

Minor aside, don't copy (or view) your array `[:]` unless you're doing something besides 1:1.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(8, 8))

# array([[2, 6, 5, 1, 1, 8, 0, 3],
#        [4, 7, 5, 4, 9, 6, 1, 8],
#        [8, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 0],
#        [7, 3, 6, 3, 0, 0, 8, 6],
#        [5, 7, 7, 0, 7, 4, 8, 6],
#        [5, 9, 4, 8, 3, 2, 2, 4],
#        [3, 4, 6, 6, 5, 2, 1, 0],
#        [3, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3]])
```

### Indexes where values meet a condition

If you feed the Boolean array (e.g. `a <= 1`) into `np.where` it returns a list of arrays where the length is equal to the number of dimensions (here, 2). Pass it to `array` and it turns the coordinate pairs into columns (e.g. (0, 3), (0, 4), which you can see are 0 or 1 in the above random data). Transposing it is handy `.T`.

```
np.array(np.where(a <= 1))
# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7],
#        [3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

### Values meeting a condition

Just index the array with the Boolean. It flattens it and returns the values.

```
a[a <= 1]
# array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

### How many values meet a condition

```
np.count_nonzero(a <= 1)
# 11
```

Comment: `sebago[:]` does not perform a copy, it just returns another view onto the values in `sebago`

Comment: @ali_m ah, you're correct. But a 1:1 view seems like pointless in this case.

Comment: For the last one, I would use `np.count_nonzero` instead. It is both more readable and considerably faster (x5 on my machine) than using `np.sum`.

Answer (score 2):

This gives you all values that are less than 200 as one dimensional array:

```
lowElv = sebago[sebago < 200]
```

Comment: I am trying to practice using numpy.where, but I guess I don't understand the syntax. I've used lowElv=np.where(sebago<200) and it returns values that are greater than 200. Do you know how I could get the same result as the code you've used using numpy.where?

Comment: `numpy.where`  returns the indices. So, this  `sebago[np.where(sebago < 200)]`  gives the same result as my answer.